# How do I get each column of the same row in one line?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this columns in excel:

```
A       B   C   D   E   F
Nima1   1   2   3   4   5
Nima2   6   7   8   9   10
Nima3   11  12  13  14  15
Nima4   16  17  18  19  20
```

and I want to show them like this:

```
Nima1   1
Nima1   2
Nima1   3
Nima1   4
Nima1   5
Nima2   6
…   
Nima4   20
```

and so far I come up with nothing, every formula that I write doesn't work.
please if anyone knows how to do it, guide me through it.

Comment: In general, showing what you have tried (working or not) helps understand parts of the problem that you failed to include in your narrative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any unused cell to the right put in this formula,

```
'for system that use a comma as a list separator
=INDEX(A:E,(ROW(1:1)-1)/5+1,IF(COLUMN(A:A)=1,1,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,5)+1))
'for system that use a semi-colon as a list separator
=INDEX(A:E;(ROW(1:1)-1)/5+1;IF(COLUMN(A:A)=1;1;MOD(ROW(1:1)-1;5)+1))
```

Fill right one column then fill both down until you get zeroes.

[image: nima1_offset]

Comment: I put your formula in the same cell but it keep showing me this error:the formula that you type contains an error.

Comment: I've added the same formula for systems that use a semi-colon as a list separator.